# Stuck! I need some help creating this footer

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, footer

This is my first post here.
I was wondering whether you could suggest to me how to make the footer in this image:
http://i5.minus.com/ik0O1e7e2qWQd.jpg

So far I have this: 
 http://www.seann.biz/testflight
 But I can't quite get the footer right. I am using bootstrap by the way. 
As you can see there are two columns of the same width but of varying colour and I would love to get these two sorted first then the rest to follow later.
This is the first full website I have coded so sorry if its a bit messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `css` `width:50%` then `float:left`, add it at the end

Something like this:

```
<div id="footer" style="width:100%;height:300px">
  <div id="footerleft" style="width:50%;height:300px;background-color:#000;float: left;"></div>
  <div id="footerright" style="width:50%;height:300px;background-color:#ccc;float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

hope this helps

**EDIT**

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X4tdz/

Add the following css to the image

- `position:absolute`
- `left:50%`
- `top:50%`
- `margin-left:-50px` // half of the image width
- `margin-top:-50px` // half of the image height

Make sure the parent div of the image is set to `position:relative`

PS: If you have any `NEW` questions make a new question about it so that others can also contribute.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! It has helped a lot actually :) now to do the hard stuff with importing twitter and spotify but making it all look nice then making it responsive so it looks like this: http://i7.minus.com/iDip8G5H2Mw1V.jpg

Comment: @seangeraghty well best of luck with that. google will help you along the way. if you can't find anything good. just ask a question here in stackoverflow. BTW, if you find my answer helpful. Pls. check it so that others will know that this question has been answered. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how I could get the Dribbble logo to centre itself in the middle of these two divs like in the image? Tried it but as the divs are separated for each side I only get the image centred in one and not the other or just centred above the whole footer? Thanks again.